# SQL - Join if ID > 0

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have the two tables "tbl_people" and "tbl_spouses".

```
tbl_people structure:
- PeopleID
- Name
- Prename
- SpouseID_FK

tbl_spouses structure:
 - SpouseID
 - Name
 - Prename
```

And so on (maybe not the best example, because spouses are also people, but whatever).

Now I want to have the prename of the peoples spouse. If `SpouseID_FK = 0`, the record should be shown aswell, but prename of spouse should be "".

```
SELECT tbl_people.PeopleID,
       tbl_people.Name,
       tbl_people.Prename, 
       tbl_spouses.Prename AS PrenameOfSpouse
FROM   tbl_people
INNER JOIN tbl_spouses ON tbl_people.SpouseID_FK = tbl_spouses.SpouseID
```

The problem with this SQL is, that it only shows the records, which don't have value 0 in `SpouseID_FK`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Unclear question but I think it can be solved using `Left Outer Join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would also show the record in `tbl_people` who don't have spouses as well.

```
SELECT tbl_people.PeopleID, tbl_people.Name, tbl_people.Prename, 
       tbl_spouses.Prename AS PrenameOfSpouse
FROM tbl_people
LEFT JOIN tbl_spouses ON tbl_people.SpouseID_FK = tbl_spouses.SpouseID
```